# Where can i get photo collection for website/template

Tags: images, legal, photo

I'm developing website templates and wonder how to get (free or buy) photos of product sample for my templates. For example, collection if furniture, shirts, lingerie? Maybe you have preferences with affordable price. Please note that these images is going to be use in  web templates for sale.

Answer (score 2):

There are many sites like this on the web, one I've heard good things about is http://www.istockphoto.com/ -- they have reasonable prices and good selection.

Comment: @Danni If you plan to resell an image purchased from iStockphoto as part of a paid website template, note that you'll need to buy the image with their Extended Licence, which allows unlimited resale of images as part of a template. Their regular (cheaper) licence doesn't allow you to redistribute images electronically at all.

Answer (score 1):

Read the license for the stock photography carefully.  In order to resell the images you usually need an extended license, which can be very expensive.  In many cases, it will be a one-use, non-resell license.

If the images in your template are just examples and the license **your** customers agree to does **not** allow them to use the images, you may not need an extended license, but you should make that clear to your buyers.

Answer (score 1):

The [Creative Commons Flickr search](http://search.creativecommons.org/?q=flowers#) finds Flickr images licensed for commercial use, adaptation, and modification.

Do check the licence terms for each image, though; you will often be required to credit the photographer by name or with a link.